# Passing variable to the url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am passing variable like that:

```
new_sub_request_path(request_id:@request.id)
```

so i get this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/sub_requests/new?request_id=1
```

In my controller i want to assign that request_id like that:

```
@sub_request = SubRequest.new(sub_request_params)
@sub_request.request_id = params[:request_id]
```

and my strong parameters are defined:

```
def sub_request_params
   params.require(:sub_request).permit(:description, :diagnos, :price, :payment, :request_id)
end
```

But after save i have empty request_id attribute, so it seems that it is not assigned. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Inspecting parameters in the console showed that i only have those attributes that are in my form.

EDIT2:

```html
 def create
    @sub_request = SubRequest.new(sub_request_params)
    @sub_request.request_id = params[:sub_request][:request_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sub_request.save
        format.html { redirect_to @sub_request, notice: 'Sub request was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @sub_request }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @sub_request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try `@sub_request.request_id = params[:sub_request][:request_id]`

Comment: @Pavan, no it doesn't help

Comment: Please post that full controller method code.

Comment: Do you have a model called `Request`?

Comment: @Pavan yes, request has_many sub_requests, and sub_request belongs_to request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define something like below for the `request_id` to save in `sub_requests` table.

In your `create` method add this line

`@request = Request.find(params[:request_id])` and do

`@sub_request.request_id = @request.id`

**or**

You can just add a `hidden_field` in your ***form*** like below

```
<%= f.hidden_field :request_id, :value => @request.id %>
```

And make sure you are permitting `:request_id` in your `sub_request_params`